# Why clicking on the immediate window speeds up the VBA code execution?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a VBA script in Excel that calculates iteratively a range of physical variables and, at each iteration, re-calculates the values of other correlated variables in the worksheet.

I have run the code from the Visual Basic editor in order to monitor the value of some variables at each iteration through the Immediate Window. I was surprised to notice a sudden acceleration of the execution simply by clicking with the mouse on the Immediate Window, or by pressing Enter. On the contrary, when the VBA script is run from the spreadsheet, its speed of execution is about five time slower, and I found no way to accelerate it.

I wonder what is the reason of the acceleration in the execution when clicking on the Immediate Window and how I could speed up the code without this trick.

I am using Excel 2013 and Windows 8.1.

Comment: we will need to review your code to give answer to your question. In your code you can be working with windows/referencing to other workbooks/sheets, use .Select or others unnecessary functions.

Comment: Some general tips & tricks on speeding up VBA code can be found, among other places, here: https://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

at the beginning of the script and

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
```

at the end of the script might possible result in the same speed up that you get by focussing the immediate-Window.

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried this, unfortunately the improvement is minor. I still have a much faster code simply clicking on the immediate window while running (which to me looks unexplicable).

Comment: I'm puzzled too. My next guess would be a bug with windows process management. Maybe Windows recognizes the process as vba-process and gives it higher priority when the VBA-window is focused but not when the excel-window is. Manually setting the process priority up might help to test that hypothesis.